# Code not reaching statements using fgets?

Tags: c, if-statement, fgets

I have written code that uses the fgets function with multiple conditions that call other functions within the code, namely aMethod and bMethod.

```
int main(void) {
char buffer[1024];
while (fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin)) {
    if ((strcasecmp(buffer,"a")) == 0) {
        aMethod();
        }
    if ((strcasecmp(buffer, "b")) == 0) {
        bMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't reach the if statements.
Any help would be great, thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt, print it out:

```
int main(void) {
char buffer[1024];
while (fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "BUFFER is [%s]\n", buffer);   /* <==== */
    if ((strcasecmp(buffer,"a")) == 0) {
        aMethod();
        }
    if ((strcasecmp(buffer, "b")) == 0) {
        bMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

you will find a lot of errors this way.

Comment: When debug printing strings, it is always a good idea to wrap it in some delimiter (square brackets in this example), as that will make it clearer what whitespace is included in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot that `fgets` consumes the `\n` character into the buffer. Strip it off by using a cool function [`strcspn()`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strcspn&sektion=3) from `string.h`. Add the following just before the `if` statements:

```
buffer[strcspn(buffer,"\n")] = 0;
```

or else, you could use the familiar `strlen()` function:

```
size_t len = strlen(buffer);

if(len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '\n')
    buffer[len-1] = 0;
```

Comment: Sorry, im kinda new to c. So the strcspn function means the length from the buffer to \n is zero?

Comment: It counts the number of characters until the second argument. In your case, it counts the number of characters until a `\n`. In case, it doesn't find a `\n`, it returns the number of characters until a `\0` which is the length of the string(`strlen(buffer)`).

Answer (score 0):

You forget that `fgets()` leaves the newline in the buffer (unless the entered line is too long).   So the input string cannot compare equal to either of the strings you are comparing with.

Also, there is no such function as `strcasecmp()` in standard C.   It is a POSIX function.