# Wrong string concatenation using strcat

Tags: c, arrays, string, file-io, fgets

I'm writing a program that reads strings from file, saves them to 'string buffer' and then concatenates those string and writes them to another file.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("Read.txt", "r");
    char line[20];
    char buff[15][20];
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(line, 18, f)) {
        strcpy(buff[i], line);
        i++;
    }
    FILE *h = fopen("Out.txt", "w+");
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        char ct[4] = "smt";
        strcat(buff[j], ct);
        fputs(buff[j], h);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Contents of file Read.txt:

```
Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit 
amet
```

Expected output (File Out.txt):

```
Lorem ipsumsmt 
dolor sitsmt 
ametsmt
```

But what I get in Out.txt:

```
Lorem ipsum 
smtdolor sit 
smtamet
smt
```

So how to get expected result?

P.S. I think that the problem occurs when I use function `fgets()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug or problem, rather, an expected behavior. Please read on.

[`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) reads and stores the trailing newline (`\n`). you need to remove (strip) that before storing the input.

That said, please note:

1. Please don't allow boundless increment of `i` when you have defined a fixed size buffer. May overflow.
2. make sure your `buff[i]` is big enough to hold the concatenated string. Otherwise, it will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Ok, so could you explain how to remove that trailing newline?

Comment: But I don't hold concatenated string in line, I hold it in buff[i]

Comment: @KiberPrestupnik many ways are there, I prefer a one-liner, `line[strchr(line, '\n') -1] = 0;` or something like this along the line.

Comment: @KiberPrestupnik You can do it the following way  size_t n = strlen( line ); if ( n && line[n-1] == '\n' ) line[n-1] = '\0';

Comment: @KiberPrestupnik yeah, that was a mistake from my side , updated.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow hey man, how're you? Don't you like the above one liner I posted?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow So kind of you. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Be warned that the suggested `line[strchr(line, '\n') -1] = 0;` will make the program crash if you enter exactly 17 characters or more. Use a safer method, such as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875285/code-not-reaching-statements-using-fgets/29875290#29875290

Comment: @Jongware Thank you for the correction. Hope OP is making a note of this.

Comment: @Natasha Dutta The code `line[strchr(line, '\n') - 1] = 0;` doesn't seem to work in MVS2015. The text of error I get: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will work for you. You need to add [Null Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) before doing any String operations. I commented the code wherever I modified.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f = fopen("Amol.txt", "r");
    char line[20];
    char buff[15][20];
    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(line, 18, f)) {
        line[strlen(line) -1] = '\0';  // Here I added NULL character 
        strcpy(buff[i], line);
        i++;
    }
    FILE *h = fopen("Out.txt", "w+");
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {       
        char ct[5] = "smt\n";       // As \n will be at the end,so changed this array
        strcat(buff[j], ct);        
        fputs(buff[j], h);
    }
    return 0;
}
```